# Why is the guitar tag a related tag to itself?

Tags: bug, tags

While looking at the [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) [top users](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/guitar/topusers), I noticed that the tag itself is a related tag:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Note that this isn't just limited to the `guitar` tag; any tag I click has itself as a related tag. Seems redundant if you ask me, and probably a bug of some kind. After all, this thread isn't shown in its own related section.

Comment: Looks likes it's all sites. You may want to check and see if it is mentioned on MSE and post about it if it's not there.